# Subsequence in compact matric space

Tags: real-analysis

Theorem -

If {p<sub>n</sub>} is a sequence in a compact metric space X, then some subsequence of {p<sub>n</sub>} converges to a point of X.

I am trying to understand the proof of this.

My attempt-

Suppose that {p<sub>n</sub>}, n from 1 to $\infty$.

Let P = {{ p<sub>n</sub>} | n $\in$ N }. If P is finite ,then there is a p $\in$ P and a sequence { n<sub>i</sub> } with n<sub>1</sub> < n<sub>2</sub> <....., Such that

p<sub>n<sub>1</sub></sub> = p<sub>n<sub>2</sub></sub> = .....= p

Therefore we have a convergent subsequence in X.

If P is infinite ,then P has a limit point 
p<sub>o</sub>  in X . 
Now since p<sub>o</sub>  is a limit point in X , there will exist a sequence in
P which will converge to p<sub>o</sub>  .

Any suggestions or hint regarding the validity of my arguments will be appreciated.

Comment: Why does $P$ being infinite imply that $P$ has a limit point in $X$?

Comment: I think because P is a infinite subset in compact metric space X .

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a compact metric space and $\{p_n\}$ a sequence of points in $X$. Let $\varepsilon>0$, then as $X$ is totally bounded there exist $x_1,\ldots,x_m\in X$ such that $$X\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^m B(x_i,\varepsilon/2). $$ For some $i$, there must be infinitely many points of $\{p_n\}$ contained in $B(x_i,\varepsilon/2)$, which comprise a subsequence $\{p_{n_k}\}$. Now for each $k,k'$ we have
$$
d(p_{n_k},p_{n_k'}) \leqslant d(p_{n_k},x_i) + d(x_i,p_{n_k'}) < \varepsilon/2 + \varepsilon/2 = \varepsilon,
$$
so $\{p_{n_k}\}$ is a Cauchy sequence. Since $X$ is complete, it follows that $\{p_{n_k}\}$ is convergent.